# Rebuild wordpress site with codeigniter

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, url, seo, rebuild

I have a client that has a website that is built with WordPress. They want to expand the site adding new features. To me it seems best to rebuild the site so WP is not being used. I like using codeigniter but one issue is how we keep our SEO rankings.

The urls in WP are something like www.foo.com/test-this-site.html

Is there a way to build the site in Codeigniter but utilize that URL structure? I basicly need to keep all the current pages working at the same url.

Does anyone know if this is possible with Codeigniter and how this may affect search ranking? Or is there a better way to go about this. Any sort of direction would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the [URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) in Code Igniter, you can customize all the link structures you want in any way you want.

You will just have to make sure you support all the same links than WordPress and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks. This answer was basically right. I used this tutorial to do what I needed. http://codearetoy.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/codeigniter-router-config-for-dynamic-url-url-shortener-or-seo-friendly-url/